# Angular Auth0 - get email claim if authenticated

Tags: angular, auth0

I want to get email claim , if user is already logged in.

```
this.auth.idTokenClaims$.forEach(e => console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>"+e.email));
```

is printing email

I want to write something like this ( because e can be null)

```
if((this.auth.isAuthenticated$ | async) === false){
      this.auth.idTokenClaims$.forEach(e => {
      this.cService.dash(e.email).subscribe(
        data => { this.yeah = data},
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('Main Content ')

      )}
      );
   } else {

    this.cService.dash(null).subscribe(
      data => { this.yeah = data},
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log('Main Content from else '));
   }
```

Problem:
if((this.auth.isAuthenticated$ | async) === false){

It says always evaluates to false, because

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'number' and
> 'boolean' have no overlap.ts(2367)

or

> The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any',
> 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)

something on these lines

Please can anyone help me resolve this

Answer (score 0):

if `isAuthenticated$` is an `Observable` or any kind of `Subject` I would try to structure the 2 streams into a `pipe` and do something like

```
this.auth.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
  skipWhile( isAuthenticated => isAuthenticated),
  switchMap( () => this.auth.idTokenClaims$ ),
  ...
).subscribe()

this.auth.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
  skipWhile( isAuthenticated => !isAuthenticated),
  switchMap( () => this.cService.dash(null) ),
  ...
).subscribe()
```

my main point here is that if you could give the types of each of the problematic variables, also `$` sign at the end mostly stands for a `Subject` or `Observable` so I don't really understand what forEach has to do without subscription

Comment: Thanks. I made a small change and that works - removed if - else part and used   ?this.cService.dash(e?.email).subscribe(

Comment: @KrisSwat your welcome! did my answer solved your question?

Comment: I used a different approach, as stated in previous comment. no more duplicate code in if and else